# Удаление предложения с расстоянием на Python

Tags: python-3.x

Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы только последнее предложение в тексте, если в нем есть фраза про километраж удалялось из текста. Но маска не работает. Программа на Python 3.7.1
Пример для работы: Автомобиль продается в городе Красноярск. Объект находится в 5 км. До города нужно ехать 15,2 км. 
Нужно, чтобы удалялось только последнее предложение. Для маски взята проверка с конца. Отсекание последнего предложения от точки и пробела (предпоследнее предложение заканчивается точкой и пробелом) + наличие цифры в последнем предложении, фразы км и последней точки.
Необходим совет как исправить.

```
import re
for a in range (0,100):
val = str(input("Введите текст: "))
res3=re.sub("(\.\s.\d.\км.\.*$", "", val)
print (res3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = """
Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы только последнее предложение в тексте, если в нем есть фраза про километраж удалялось из текста. Но маска не работает. Программа на Python 3.7.1 Пример для работы: Автомобиль продается в городе Красноярск. Объект находится в 5 км. До города нужно ехать 15,2 км.
"""

rez = ". ".join(s.strip().split (". ")[:-1])+"." if re.findall ("(\d км\.*$)", s.strip()) else s

print(rez)
Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы только последнее предложение в тексте, если в нем есть фраза про километраж удалялось из текста. Но маска не работает. Программа на Python 3.7.1 Пример для работы: Автомобиль продается в городе Красноярск. Объект находится в 5 км.
```

Comment: Не работает код. Пример текста: Сотрудники организуют прокат автомобиля. Театр имени Шота Руставели находится в 4 км от салона.

Comment: Попробуйте так: `rez = ". ".join(s.strip().split (". ")[:-1])+"." if re.findall ("(\d км*)", s.strip()) else s`